# Automatic update without play store

Tags: android, google-play, apk, auto-update, android-package-managers

I wonder if there's a way to update whole app without Play Store SDK(but download from my server).(Not only XML, but also all of code and configs)And without any pop ups to touch.

As far as I know, it's prohibited. One method that I know about update without play store is like this: [Automatically install Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836318/automatically-install-android-application)

However, I guess Xiomi Applications achieved this feature(auto update).

I found [this page](http://www.auto-update-apk.com/manual)
And it has [Github Repository](https://github.com/lazydroid/auto-update-apk-client)

It has SlientAutoUpdate Class and it's experimental. And it seems the device must be rooted to use command codes such as `su`.

Is there any way without rooting?

I want the users not to touch anything to update the app.

Comment: this can be achieved by using MDM server only.

Comment: Do you have any links about it?

Answer (score 0):

in [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34251575/how-to-autoupdate-android-app-without-playstore-like-facebook-app-or-any-contes) topic you have multiple samples for auto-update, but these still need some user interaction (at least "Install"/"Update" button click on some system screen)

but there is also another method for changing source code without reinstalling APK, so-called hot-fixing. check out these libs:

- [Tinker](https://github.com/Tencent/tinker)
- [AndFix](https://github.com/alibaba/AndFix)
- [Amigo](https://github.com/eleme/Amigo)

worth noting: Google is forbidding using these hot-fix libs/ways. note that developer can release some APK and some day it may add some extra code only from its server side, users just runs again app. then dev may trick user to grant some new permission or turn on some feature (users trusts this app, is using it for a while) allowing to execute some not-friendly code (e.g. some virus, malware, ads etc.), which wasn't present at the moment of uploading APK to Google Play Store console (which is scanning all APKs uploaded as update, may refuse publishing)

Comment: um.. So, it doesn't update whole app but just like some classes? for hot fix. It's all in Chinese. It'd be great if you have better resources.. @snachmsm

Comment: sadly I've never used that feature, just know that exists...